Example of a complete valued field that does not satisfy hensel's lemma
A valued field $(K,v)$ is henselian if it satisfies hensel's lemma.
Notation : $O_v$ is   the valuation ring of $(K,v)$ (it is a local ring), $F_v$ is the residue field of $F_v$.
Hensel's Lemma : for all $f \in O_v [X]$, $a \in O_v$ with $\overline{f}(\overline{a})=0$ and $\overline{f'}(\overline{a}) \neq 0$ in the residue field. There existe some $b \in O_v$ such that $f(b)=0$ and $\overline{b}= \overline{a}$.
It is a fact that a complete field equipped with a rank 1 discrete valuation is Henselian. But in literature it is stated that there exists some complete fields with higher rank valuation that are not henselian hence the introduction of the henselization of fields. However, I could not find an example of a complete field valued field that does not satisfy hensel's lemma.
Any help on this is much appreciated.
